# How to fix a glitchy header collapsing to nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, navigation

I'm trying to create a header that slowly collapses to a navigation bar as you scroll down (The height of the header decreases as you scroll down until it reaches a height of 70px, when it becomes sticky to the top of the screen).
I have managed to achieve this, however it is extremely glitchy and it is probably not the "cleanest" way of handling it... This is what I have done: http://www.stroba.uk .
As you can see, it is quite glitchy and not smooth at all.
I have also created a simplified jsfiddle of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/uvwusfy2/ .
Does anyone know how I can fix this "glitchiness"? Whether it be a different way of doing it or improving my way of doing it?

If the way i'm doing it confuses you, here's an explanation:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="header">
        This is the header that should turn into a nav bar as you scroll down to where it has a height of 70px
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
        This is some content...<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I create the header, the content and a space div, which I will later fill using jQuery.

**CSS**

```
div.Container {
color:white;
font-family:arial;
}
div.space {
    width:100%
    height:0px;
}
div.header {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      #5d9634,
      #5d9634 50%,
      #538c2b 50%,
      #538c2b
    );
    background-size: 100% 20px;
}
div.header nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
div.content {
    height: 1500px;
    background-color:blue;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      #606dbc,
      #606dbc 10px,
      #465298 10px,
      #465298 20px
    );
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var initialHeaderHeight = $("div.header").height();
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var headerHeight = $("div.header").height();
        if (st < initialHeaderHeight - 70) {
            $("div.header").height(initialHeaderHeight - $(window).scrollTop());
            $("div.space").height($(window).scrollTop());
            $("div.header").css("position", "relative");
            $("div.content").css("top", "0");
        } else {
            $("div.header").css("position", "fixed");
            $("div.header").css("top", "0");
            $("div.content").css("top", "70px");
        }
    })
});
```

Here, I make it so that as the user scrolls down the page, the header gets smaller and the "space" div gets bigger and takes up the space that the header took up before the user scrolled down, so that it seems like the content scrolls up and the header gets smaller.
I'm sorry that this might be hard to understand, but i'd just like to know if there is any way I can improve on the code so that the process of scrolling down the page is much smoother and much less glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you want to make as few jQuery calls as possible, to avoid performance bottlenecks.

Your code does repeated DOM lookups every time the `$(window).scroll` event fires - which happens very often when the user scrolls. Each time you make a jQuery function call, say `$('div.header')`, jQuery has to look up the entire document to retrieve the element (`div.header`). This is a slow step, which needs to complete before the CSS properties of the element can be modified.

To optimize your code, retrieve references to the `.header`, `.space`, and `.content` elements a single time when the DOM loads, store them, and use them in your animation calls. You can see this and a few other optimizations below:

```
$(function () {
    // retrieve and store header, space and content:
    var $header = $('div.header'),
        $space = $('div.space'),
        $content = $('div.content'),
        initialHeaderHeight = $header.height(),
        // declare variables to use in the event handler,
        // to avoid redeclaring them at every call:
        st,
        headerHeight;

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        st = $(window).scrollTop();
        headerHeight = $header.height();
        if (st < initialHeaderHeight - 70) {
            // reuse the $space, $header, $content, and st values, 
            // to avoid repeated $("") and $(window).scrollTop() calls:
            $header.height(initialHeaderHeight - st);
            $space.height(st);
            $header.css("position", "relative");
            $content.css("top", "0");
        } else {
            // reuse $header and $content to avoid
            // repeated $("") calls, and
            // use alternative .css() syntax to eliminate
            // additional .css() call on $header:
            $header.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: 0
            });
            $content.css("top", "70px");
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:**

A further improvement is to keep the `.header` always anchored to the top of the viewport, adjust it's height based on the scroll value, and use the `.space` element only to position the `.content` when scrolling.

First, give your header fixed positioning:

```
div.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Next, when the page loads, set the spacer element's height to the initial height of your header. When the user scrolls, the spacer will position the content element in the way that you need:

```
$space.height(initialHeaderHeight);
```

And finally, update the height of the header based on the current scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    st = e.delegateTarget.scrollY; // get scrollDiff from scroll event
    if (st < initialHeaderHeight - 70) {
        headerHeight = initialHeaderHeight - st;
    } else {
        headerHeight = 70;
    }
    $header.height(headerHeight);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stiliyan/k9zjvLtw/)

Comment: This definitely does smooth the process out a little, however it is still not as smooth as it could be.. See updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvwusfy2/4/ and updated site: http://www.stroba.uk.  The process becomes more "choppy" as you scroll up the page.

Comment: Hi @Jubs, I'm seeing you will still have to use the variables in your scroll event callback. You have to eliminate the calls to the `$("")` function and replace them with the variables you initialized at the beginning if the script. See the `$(window).scroll()` event callback in the answer above.

Comment: Sorry @Stiliyan, I linked you to the wrong fiddle, here is the updated one that I meant to link to: https://jsfiddle.net/uvwusfy2/8/, as you can see, it is still reasonably glitchy. Would you know a way to fix this?

Comment: @Jubs, just updated my answer with a further improvement, which should resolve the "glitches". In the old fiddles margin and padding around the `body` caused flicker when the header's positioning changed. Also, when scrolling up on slower systems, the header would visibly lag behind. With the updated solution, the header remains anchored to the top of the viewport - and only its bottom boundary expands or collapses, which gives it a more natural behavior, even if there's a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a proper CSS rule there for `transition` as below:

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uvwusfy2/3/)**

```
div.header {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      #5d9634,
      #5d9634 50%,
      #538c2b 50%,
      #538c2b
    );
    transition: height 500ms; //Add this line
    background-size: 100% 20px;
}
```

hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: This definitely makes it smoother, however it causes a sort of delay to the resizing, which is quite visible when you scroll up and lots of white space appears on top of the header (I tried reducing the time of the transition but that just reduced the effect of the transition).

Comment: If you want it smooth then definitely how its gona work! Not clear how you want it actually!